# Python start from a specific string line and write?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to match a specific string and once match start writing the next line after after the matched string.

from output save in x variable I want to match "Current configuration" then write then start writing from next line.

Heres the sample output sting.

```
show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1505 bytes
!
Content1
Content1
!
Content2
Content2
```

once matched write but starting from next line. heres the target output.

```
!
Content1
Content1
!
Content2
Content2
```

Sample Configuration(but string the for line and not matching):

```
str = """show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1505 bytes
!
Content1
Content1
!
Content2
Content2"""

with open('test.txt', 'w') as x:
    print str
    if "Current configuration" in str:
        x.writelines(itertools.islice(str, 4, None))
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're having?

Comment: split text into lines and use `for-loop` to find line with `"Current configuration"` and then write rest to file.

Comment: Yes, but what is your CURRENT code block doing that is not what you want? I understand what you're trying to solve, but what is it that your code is currently doing wrong?

Comment: @blackbrandt, Yes, Correct my code is very different that my target output. tho maybe with I can tweak/make adjust so that I can achieve the target output? Thanks

Comment: @furas, thanks. let me take a look of that. but if you can share the sample code will be better.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.islice` works on *characters* of a string, not *lines*.  So you'll need to break up your text into lines:

```
x.write("\n".join(itertools.islice(str.split("\n"), 4, None)))
```

Comment: Thanks this work, Though how can I use itertool to match a specific string/word then from it I can start the print?

Answer (score 0):

I would split text into lines and then use `for` loop with `enumerate()` to find line with text. After then I would write rest of text.

```
text = """show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1505 bytes
!
Content1
Content1
!
Content2
Content2"""

lines = text.split('\n')

for number, line in enumerate(lines): # get line and its number
    if "Current configuration" in line:
        print(number, '>', line)

        rest_text = '\n'.join(lines[idx+1:]) # join lines in one text

        with open('test.txt', 'w') as x:
            x.write(rest_text)
            break  # exit `for` loop
```